# Make the Stack Overflow Blog more prominent / discoverable

Tags: discussion

While Stack Overflow is like a homepage for me, I am not a regular visitor on Meta. The only reason I am visiting Meta (if I do not want to search or ask something) is because I saw something interesting in the `FEATURED ON META` or `HOT META POSTS` on side-bar.

[image]

After this, for sure I will stick around a little and will read various and, in most cases, irrelevant Q&As.

Wouldn't it be nice to have something similar for the [Stack Overflow Blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/)? IMHO the blog has some really good posts, so why not to promote / advertise them more? We are also doing something similar with the `Hot Network Questions`

What we can do is to add a similar to that 'meta box' component on the sidebar (or an additional row on the 'meta box'), <s>showing the most popular</s> or the newest blog post.

**Update**

Seems that I totally missed the 'Notification' regarding blog on the Sidebar yellow bulletin.

To prove myself wrong, here is a screenshot

[image]

Comment: We get weekly mail for hot posts.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I was not aware of that to tell the truth, I am not getting any e-mail.  I will check it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We already do advertise Stack Overflow blog posts in the community bulletin (that yellow sidebar that has the "Featured on Meta" and "Hot Meta Posts" lists). We only advertise *new* blog posts, though, not "popular" ones. When a new post is published to the blog, a link to that post appears in the community bulletin for 3 days.

The goal of the community bulletin is to draw attention to announcements or discussions that are likely to be timely, interesting, and important to the community...old blog posts are not likely to meet all of those criteria, so I don't know that we'd ever consider including them in this space. "Hot" meta posts are ones that are generating a lot of activity, but old blog posts don't get much interaction from users, so they'd never be considered "hot" in the same way that meta posts are.

Comment: FWIW, the blog is also linked from the site switcher in the topbar and in the footer on every page.

Comment: @Laura Thank you for the prompt answer. I agree that 'Hot' may not have a meaning for blog post and 'new' is more suitable for the case. However I can not recall any blog advertise in bulletin. Probably is my mistake or I do not pay enough attention and possible it was there and I missed it.

Comment: @AdamLear I am already aware of this but thanks for mentioned it again.